# $P = NP\text{ if and only if } \exists p \in NP-\text{ complete such that } p \in P$

Tags: computational-complexity, np-complete

> $$P = NP\text{ if and only if } \exists p \in NP-\text{ complete such that } p \in P$$

Is this statement true? I can prove the first direction $\rightarrow$ but I have difficulties in showing that, supposing $\exists p \in NP-\text{ complete such that } p \in P$, this implies $P = NP$.

Comment: Think about what it means that $p$ is NP complete. If $p$ is then also in $P$, what consequences must that have?

Comment: If a problem is NP-complete it means that every NP problem is reducible to it. But can I say that if a problem q in NP is reducible to a problem p in P in PTIME, then the problem q can be solved in PTIME?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The definition of $NP$-complete is

> $p$ is $NP$-complete iff any $NP$ problem may be reduced to $p$ in polynomial time

(at least for the purposes of this question). If any $NP$-problem may be reduced to $p$ in polynomial time, and $p\in P$, what does that say about all $NP$-problems?

Comment: Probably I misunderstood the meaning of the reduction from all NP-problem to the problem p. Can I say that if a problem q in NP is reducible to a problem p in P in PTIME, then the problem q can be solved in PTIME?
It seems to me that I'm using the reduction in the "wrong" way

Comment: @LucaDiLiello "Reduction" basically means "translation", but we call it reducing because usually you do it to make a problem simpler. But yes, if you have a polynomial time algorithm to translate $q$ into a problem you know can be solved in polynomial time, then $q$ itself can be solved in polynomial time.

Comment: This was the concept I was missing. Thank you